# Triangular inequality for the Norm in the field extension

Tags: normed-spaces, resultant

Let K(a) be a field extension of field K with algebraic number a. 
It is well known that Norm(bc)=Norm(b)Norm(c) for b and c in K(a). 
It can be proved by the property of polynomial resultant. In general, the term "Norm" should satisfy the triangle inequality. Is it true in the field extension case? thanks

Comment: Do you want to assume that $K$ is an ordered field? Otherwise, the triangle inequality doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The meanings of the word "Norm" in algebra and analysis are quite different.
The norm in fields does not generally satisfy the triangle inequality, even in an ordered field.  For example, the norms of $1\pm\sqrt{2}$ (over the rationals) are $-1$, while the norm of $2 = (1+\sqrt{2}) + (1-\sqrt{2})$ is $4$.

Comment: The norm of $2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $4$, no? Though the example would still be correct.

Comment: @llf Thanks, I made an edit to fix the typo.

Answer (score 1):

No in general. For example, $K=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $a,b\in \mathbf{Z}$ a solution to Pell equation: $a^2-2b^2=1$ with $b$ large enough. Take $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $y=-a+b\sqrt{2}$. Then $x+y=2b\sqrt{2}$, thus $|N(x+y)|=8b^2$, while $N(x)=N(y)=1$. So, we cannot control $|N(x+y)|$ with $|N(x)|,|N(y)|, K$.